# Spring Webflow: How to change the destination of a transition in a child flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm using Spring Webflow 2 and I have the following parent flow:

```
<flow ...>
  ...
  <view-state id="show-task">
    <transition on="approve" to="search">
      <!-- lots of things -->
    </transition>
    <!-- several other transitions and other instructions -->
  </view-state>
</flow>
```

I have a child flow and in it, I want to replace the `"search"` you see above to `"execute"` without modifying the parent flow (except if it is to make it more generic). The "lots of things" must still be executed without being copied/pasted to the child flow.

How to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: i don't think this is a good idea. it seems really confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

I see a couple of options:

- You change your parent flow to have a boolean input that you check in a decision state the value of this input to decide if you need to go to "search" (include null value in this case so you don't have to change your children's code) or "execute" as a result of your approve transition.
- Change your logic so that the parent goes to an end state on "approve" and use outputs if needed, so that the child can transition on this end state and do what it has to do.
- You create a new transition in your child flow and copy "lots of things" in it with a different "to" state.

I like #1 better and I thing this is the way to go. The parent should know about the different possible outcomes of its transitions. or #2 the parent need to be done in order for the child to decide what else it needs to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked with my code manager and we decided to go with option 2 as it seems the most flexible in case we want to reuse the mechanism (and we will).